# Java ';' expected error

Tags: java, android, datepickerdialog

I'm struggling for some days with some code. Many tries, see my other questions.  Now they expect a ";" but I don't know why.

```
holder.valueLabel.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (item.value.equals(""))
                try {
                    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
                    holder.valueLabel.setText(date);
                    mItems.get(position).value = date;
                    showDatePickerDialog(holder.valueLabel.getText().toString(), (datePicker, year, month, day) -> {
                        String dateInFormat = getDateInFormat(year, month, day);
                        holder.valueLabel.setText(dateInFormat);
                        mItems.get(position).value = dateInFormat;

                        (DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE), "cancel", (DialogInterface.OnClickListener) (dialog, which) -> {
                            if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {
                                mItems.get(position).value = "";
                            } else {
                                mItems.get(position).value = dateInFormat;
                            }
                            ----->}); <--------------

                    }).show();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            else {
                try {
                    showDatePickerDialog(holder.valueLabel.getText().toString(), (datePicker, year, month, day) -> {
                        String dateInFormat = getDateInFormat(year, month, day);
                        holder.valueLabel.setText(dateInFormat);
                        mItems.get(position).value = dateInFormat;
                    }).show();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
});
```

ShowDatePickerDialog

```
private DatePickerDialog showDatePickerDialog(String date, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener) throws ParseException {
    Calendar myCalendar = getDateFromFormat(date);
    return new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), R.style.AppTheme_DialogTheme, listener,
            myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    );

}
```

Comment: Write the stacktrace in order to know in which lane you need the ";"

Comment: Yes I was editing the question @AMB

Comment: try to add opening and close brace to  if (item.value.equals("")){}

Comment: remove bracket  and write like this. try };

Comment: Post your showDatePickerDialog() code.

Comment: add '('  opening bracket after (DialogInterface.OnClickListener) ( .

Comment: @HareshChhelana I post it! I want if the user hits the cancel button, that the edittextfield empty is. And not filled with the current date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not properly implement DatePickerDialog methods try below way resolve error what you are getting :

```
holder.valueLabel.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (item.value.equals(""))
                try {
                    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
                    holder.valueLabel.setText(date);
                    mItems.get(position).value = date;
                    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = showDatePickerDialog(holder.valueLabel.getText().toString(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            String dateInFormat = getDateInFormat(year, month, day);
                            holder.valueLabel.setText(dateInFormat);
                            mItems.get(position).value = dateInFormat;
                        }

                    });
                    datePickerDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "cancel", (dialog, which) -> {
                        holder.valueLabel.setText("");
                        mItems.get(position).value = "";
                    });
                    datePickerDialog.show();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            else {
                try {
                    showDatePickerDialog(holder.valueLabel.getText().toString(), (datePicker, year, month, day) -> {
                        String dateInFormat = getDateInFormat(year, month, day);
                        holder.valueLabel.setText(dateInFormat);
                        mItems.get(position).value = dateInFormat;
                    }).show();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: The code works fine. Thanks so much! In the debugger the cancel button give a response. But how can I clean the value? 

I filled in mItems.get(position).value = ""; Thats not the right way. Any suggestions?`

Comment: I fixed it, yes your solution was right. Thank you so much. works like a charm

Comment: if I open the calendar, and when I pressed the back button the field is filled. Is that possible to solve? It must clean.